Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract OC is ERC20, Ownable {
    uint256 private constant TOTAL_SUPPLY = 1000000 * 10**18; // 1M OC
    uint256 public feePercentage = 1; // %1 fee
    address public feeRecipient = 0x; // OWNER WALLET
    address public mintRecipient = 0x; //owner mint Wallet

    constructor() ERC20("OC", "OC") Ownable(msg.sender) {
        _mint(mintRecipient, TOTAL_SUPPLY);
    }

    function setFeeRecipient(address _feeRecipient) external onlyOwner {
        require(_feeRecipient != address(0), "Fee recipient address cannot be zero address");
        feeRecipient = _feeRecipient;
    }

    function setMintRecipient(address _mintRecipient) external onlyOwner {
        require(_mintRecipient != address(0), "Mint recipient address cannot be zero address");
        mintRecipient = _mintRecipient;
    }

  function _transfer (address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount)  internal  override {
    
    uint256 feeAmount = (amount * feePercentage) / 100;
    uint256 transferAmount = amount - feeAmount;

    require(balanceOf(sender) >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

    super._transfer(sender, feeRecipient, feeAmount); 
    super._transfer(sender, recipient, transferAmount ); 
}
}


You can't override the _transfer function as it is not a virtual function. This is also written in the OZ contract comments.

To override any transfer operation, you need to override the _update function.
Replace the _transfer function with this _update function.
function _update(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal override {
        if (from == address(0)) {
            // Minting
            super._update(from, to, amount);
        } else if (to == address(0)) {
            // Burning
            super._update(from, to, amount);
        } else {
            // Regular transfer with fee
            uint256 feeAmount = (amount * feePercentage) / 100;
            uint256 transferAmount = amount - feeAmount;

            super._update(from, feeRecipient, feeAmount); // Transfer fee
            super._update(from, to, transferAmount);      // Transfer remaining amount
        }
    }

This should work as expected.

Assuming the title is your question ...
The reason you're experiencing this error is because you're using override on your implementation of _transfer.
_transfer is not virtual in the base ERC20 contract you've imported and extended from. Therefore, you cannot use override here.
Instead, you should read the OpenZeppelin ERC20 contract implementation on Github. There's a commented notice about editing the _update function to achieve your desired outcome.
